# Why is ng-grid not sorting by both columns?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have 2 grids showing the same data with 2 different sorts:

```
$scope.aGridOptions = {
  data: 'aData',
  columnDefs: [
    { displayName: 'Column 1', field: 'col1',}, 
    { displayName: 'Column2',  field: 'col2',}],
  sortInfo: {
    fields: ['col1'], directions: ['asc']
  },
};
$scope.bGridOptions = {
  data: 'aData',
  columnDefs: [
    { displayName: 'Column 1', field: 'col1',}, 
    { displayName: 'Column2',  field: 'col2',}],
  sortInfo: {
    fields: ['col1', 'col2'],
    directions: ['asc', 'asc']
  },
};
```

As the plunker shows, both sort the same way, only by column 1.  Not only that, but ng-grid 2.0.7, trashes by sortInfo object on `bGridOptions` to shorten the sort to only one column.

http://plnkr.co/edit/riDzDcS3YSJrQrULwL2j?p=preview

I can't seem to find where it is destroying my sort options.  How do I get it to sort by 2 columns and not have it trash my sortInfo?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the initial answer I typed, which seemed to work as I played around in your Plunk; however, when I went to make a clean copy of the Plunk it stopped working. It sounds like this issue may be resolved in 2.0.8 though, see [Issue #748](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/748) and  [Issue #732](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/732).

> **My initial response, but not working for me now...**
>
> Try changing the `sortInfo` for each grid to look like this:
>
> ```
> $scope.aGridOptions.sortInfo = {
>   fields: ['col1'],
>   directions: ['asc'],
>   columns: [0]
> };
> $scope.bGridOptions.sortInfo = {
>   fields: ['col1', 'col2'],
>   directions: ['asc', 'asc'],
>   columns: [0, 1]
> };
> ```